# Where is the configuration file for HDFS in Hadoop 2.2.0?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs, configuration-files

I'm studying Hadoop and currently I'm trying to set up an Hadoop 2.2.0 single node. I downloaded the latest distribution, uncompressed it, now I'm trying to set up the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS).

Now, I'm trying to follow the Hadoop instructions available [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Single_Node_Setup) but I'm quite lost.

In the left bar you see there are references to the following files:

- core-default.xml
- hdfs-default.xml
- mapred-default.xml
- yarn-default.xml

But how those files are ?

I found /etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml, but it is empty!

I found /share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml but it is just a piece of doc!

So, what files I have to modify to configure HDFS ? Where the deaults values are read from ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For Installing Hadoop 2.2.0 You follow [this link](http://learninghadoopblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/hadoop-0-23-9-single-node-setup-on-ubuntu-13-04/). It is for "0.23.9" but it works absolutely fine for "2.2.0"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These files are all found in the hadoop/conf directory.

For setting HDFS you have to configure core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml.

HDFS works in two modes: distributed (multi-node cluster) and pseudo-distributed (cluster of one single machine).

For the pseudo-distributed mode you have to configure:

In core-site.xml:

```
<!-- namenode -->
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

In hdfs-site.xml:

```
<-- storage directories for HDFS - the hadoop.tmp.dir property, whose default is /tmp/hadoop-${user.name} -->
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/your-dir/</value>
</property>
```

Each property has its hardcoded default value.

Please remember to set ssh password-less login for hadoop user before starting HDFS.

P.S.

It you download Hadoop from Apache, you can consider switching to a Hadoop distribution:

[Cloudera's CDH](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cdh.html), HortonWorks or MapR.

If you install Cloudera CDH or Hortonworks HDP you will find the files in /etc/hadoop/conf/.

Comment: Thanks to pointing me to Cloudera's CDH. Currently my intention is to understand how to work with Hadoop from scratch, if you know what I mean, just to understand at least all the pieces. I agree a distribution like the one you pointed at could be quicker solution.

Comment: In that case I recommend you to read Oreilly's Hadoop Definitive Guide 2012 Edition.

Answer (score 5):

> **For Hortonworks location would be**

```
/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

All the configuration files will be located in the extracted tar.gz file in the etc/hadoop/ directory. The hdfs-site.xml may be hdfs-site.xml.template. You will need to rename it to hdfs-site.xml.

If you want to see what options for hdfs check the doc in the tarball in share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Answer (score 2):

For `hadoop 3.2`, the default config can be found at:

- Local installation

  ```
  $HADOOP_HOME/share/doc/hadoop/
      hadoop-project-dist/
          hadoop-common/
              core-default.xml
          hadoop-hdfs/
              hdfs-default.xml

      hadoop-mapreduce-client/
          hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/
              mapred-default.xml

      hadoop-yarn/
          hadoop-yarn-common/
              yarn-default.xml
  ```
- Online (at http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/, the `Configuration` part on left bottom):

  - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml
  - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml
  - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml
  - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml
- Effective config, in web console of local instance.
  If you didn't change config, then default config is shown.
  e.g

  - namenode: `http://localhost:9870/conf`

Answer (score 1):

these files can be seen here /usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop, in that location u can find all the XMLs.