# Where exactly should hadoop.tmp.dir be set? core-site.xml or hdfs-site.xml?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs, configuration-files

I'm asking about the Hadoop 2.x series. There's conflicting advice about this on the Internet. Like in this [case](https://cxwangyi.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/specify-the-local-directory-for-hdfs-storage/) where he asks to specify it in `core-site.xml` and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21390641/4240292) where it is mentioned that `hadoop.tmp.dir` be set in `hdfs-site.xml`. Which is the right place to put it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hadoop.tmp.dir` (A base for other temporary directories) is property, that need to be set in `core-site.xml`, it is like export in linux

Ex:

```
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name</value>
```

You can use reference of `hadoop.tmp.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml` like above

For more [core-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml) and [hdfs-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

There're three HDFS properties which contain hadoop.tmp.dir in their values

`dfs.name.dir`: directory where namenode stores its metadata, with default value `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name.`

`dfs.data.dir`: directory where HDFS data blocks are stored, with default value `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`.

`fs.checkpoint.dir`: directory where secondary namenode store its checkpoints, default value is  `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/namesecondary`

Comment: And a little tangential to this but, `hadoop.tmp.dir` is the location where hdfs stores all of its data, right?